# How to remove the name "Queryset" from queryset data that has been retrieved in Django Database?

Tags: django, pandas, django-queryset

we all know that if we need to retrieve data from the database the data will back as a queryset but the question is How can I retrieve the data from database which is the name of it is queryset but remove that name from it.

maybe I can't be clarified enough in explanation so you can look at the next example to understand what I mean:

```
AnyObjects.objects.all().values()
```

this line will back the data like so:

```
<QuerySet [{'key': 'value'}]
```

now you can see the first name that is on the left side of retrieving data which is: "QuerySet" so, I need to remove that name to make the data as follows:

```
[{'key': 'value'}]
```

if you wonder about why so, the abbreviation of answer is I want to use Dataframe by pandas so, to put the data in Dataframe method I should use that layout.

any help please!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list(…)` to convert it to a list of dictionaries:

```
list(AnyObjects.objects.values())
```

You will need to serialize it with the `json` package to obtain a JSON blob, since strings with single quotes are not valid JSON, in order to make it a JSON blob, you can work with:

```
import json

json.dumps(list(AnyObjects.object.values()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to change it from a Queryset to anything else; [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) can take any Iterable as data. So

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(djangoapp.models.Model.objects.all().values())
```

Gives you the DataFrame you expect. (though you may want to double check `df.dtypes`. If there are `None`s in your data, the column may end up to be of `object` type.)